# Getting entity list with ids on Hibernate 5.3

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I just started using Hibernate, and I'm using it to build a RESTful API with Jersey.

In order to get used to Hibernate, I'm trying to implement the CRUD operations for this entity (I've excluded the getters, setters and annotations for convenience):

```
public class People  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private String surname;
 private String phone;
 private String email;
 private String dui;
 private String address;
 private Boolean state;
 private Set userses = new HashSet(0);

 public People() {
 }


 public People(String name, String surname, String phone, String email, String dui, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.dui = dui;
    this.address = address;
 }
 public People(String name, String surname, String phone, String email, String dui, String address, Boolean state, Set userses) {
   this.name = name;
   this.surname = surname;
   this.phone = phone;
   this.email = email;
   this.dui = dui;
   this.address = address;
   this.state = state;
   this.userses = userses;
 }

}
```

Since I want to get the list of records for this entity but NOT its children (userses in this case [yeah, I know that field has a funny name]), I'm fetching the list using the constructor of the entity:

```
  SessionFactory sesFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
  Session ses = sesFact.openSession();
  Transaction tra = null;
  tra = ses.beginTransaction();
  String queryString = "SELECT new People(p.name, p.surname, p.phone, p.email, p.dui, p.address) FROM People p";
  Query query = ses.createQuery(queryString, People.class);
  List<People> people = query.list();
```

The problem with that approach is that I get the list of entities WITHOUT their respective ids, and I need to have them in the returning list (...Unless Hibernate has a particular reason for not doing that, which I'm not aware of. If there's such a thing, I'll be thankful if you point that out).

So, what's the best approach to achieve that?

I see that none of the constructors generated by Hibernate takes the id as an argument. Is there a reason for that?

I could create a custom constructor that includes the id as a parameter, but I don't really want to change the generated POJO since it's very likely that my database will change, and I don't want to lose all my hardcoded stuff if I auto-regenerate the POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I came up with a solution myself.

While trying out different approaches, most of the time I ended up with a *LazyInitializationException*. I kept blaming Hibernate for the problem, as I thought that it was firing the Exceptions by itself, immediately after running the query. However, I failed to realize that the loading of the relationships was being triggered when Jersey tried to Serialize the entities to JSON, hence throwing the Exceptions due to the Relationships being Lazy Loaded. So the problem was Jersey and not Hibernate. A funny chain of confusions due to the fact that I'm not used to Hibernate.

Finally, the approach that I took is to use the "standard" HQL form of retrieving lists, which returns the entities with all of its fields (including the ids), then nullifying the relationships of each entity of the fetched list before returning it to the Jersey Servlet:

```
tra = ses.beginTransaction();
String queryString = "FROM People";
Query query = ses.createQuery(queryString, People.class);
List<People> people = query.list();

for (People p : people) {
    p.setUserses(null);
}

return people;
```

As a result, I get the list of People without their children relationships.

*However, I'm not completely sure if this is the best posible approach, since that if I apply this for a case in which I need to join various entities, I will end up with a lot of nested foreachs for nullifying the not desired relationships of every involved entity.*

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't much be better if you make your entity to an DTO? if you don't want to get the mapped list from your parent.

something like this

`

```
public class PeopleDTO {

 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private String surname;
 private String phone;
 private String email;
 private String dui;
 private String address;
 private Boolean state;

 public PeopleDTO() {
 }


 public PeopleDTO(String name, String surname, String phone, String email, String dui, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.dui = dui;
    this.address = address;
 }
```

`

`String queryString = "SELECT new PeopleDTO(p.name, p.surname, p.phone, p.email, p.dui, p.address) FROM People p";`

Comment: I guess that would be a better approach for the case showed in the question, where only one entity is fetched. But, in a case in which I also need to fetch some relationships (For example, if I wanted a list of People and their respective Users), wouldn't it become complicated to call a constructor with said relationship (which has to be a instance of Set)? I tried calling the 'full' constructor of the entity for that case, but didn't find the way to pass the Set as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: if you could, you can try adding the mapped `Entity` that you want. see the example

`SELECT new PeopleDTO(p.name, p.surname, p.phone, p.email, p.dui, p.address, u ) FROM People p JOIN p.userses  u` and then add the `userses` as  `Set` on the DTO